# Are aio_read, aio_write buffered by kernel? In case of Linux, does they go through page cache?

Tags: linux, asynchronous, io, buffer

The question is as the title.
In Linux, passing `O_DIRECT` bypass the page cache done by buffer. For example, database system will use it to manage its own buffer.

I wonder is `aio_write`/`aio_read` buffered by default or not? They are queued of course, but does that involve copying data? If they are buffered by default, probably we can just `open` the file without passing `O_DIRECT`, though passing `O_DIRECT` in every circumstance will bypass the kernel page cache for normal files.

The [POSIX standards](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/) seems to suggest that aio_read/aio_write are not buffered by kernel:

> Effect of Buffering
>
> If asynchronous I/O is performed on a file that is buffered prior to
> being actually written to the device, it is possible that asynchronous
> I/O will offer no performance advantage over normal I/O; the cycles
> stolen to perform the asynchronous I/O will be taken away from the
> running process and the I/O will occur at interrupt time. This
> potential lack of gain in performance in no way obviates the need for
> asynchronous I/O by realtime applications, which very often will use
> specialized hardware support, multiple processors, and/or unbuffered,
> synchronized I/O.

However, there are no definite words when describing aio_read/aio_write about buffering.

Comment: That is a question about Linux, not C.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a question on Linux specific system calls.

Comment: @vonbrand Why do you think that's off-topic? ["... if your question generally covers… a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development … then you’re in the right place to ask your question!"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: @vonbrand Just see your profile. It include a tag named "Linux". Aren't part of those Linux specific questions?

Comment: The linux/glibc implementation of the POSIX aio functions uses threads that call normal synchronous syscalls like `read()` and `write()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. They go through the kernel cache. `aio_fsync` attests this.